# PHP Tagging System - trouble with SESSION

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to implement a tagging system for my comics site.

The goal is similar to SO- a user can click on multiple tags, and those tags stay with them - the main difference being I'm using $_SESSION to store them, not a login system that SO has.

Once a user clicks on a tag, it will limit the comics shown to those that match the tag id. It was suggested that I have 3 separate tables- one for Comics, one for Tags, and a relational table ComicTags. A comic can have 0 or many tags, and a tag can be associated with 1 or many comics.

I'm struggling to write the correct sql query that will connect a comic id with 0 or many tag ids.

Would my tables be set up like this?

[image]

Would my query to retreive those be like this?

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM comics c INNER JOIN comictags ct ON (c.id = ct.comicID) WHERE ct.tagID IN (1, 2, 3) GROUP BY c.id");
```

Thanks!

---

EDIT

Am I visualizing this correctly?

1) First select all columns from comics and tags...

2) Join comic id's to their matching id's in ComicTags table

3) Join tag id's to their matching id's in ComicTags table

4) in this case, SELECT only those WHERE tag id is 1 or 2... So that would return all of the comic IDs...

[image]

---

EDIT 2: Code

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'dbconnect.php';

$site = (isset($_GET['site']) ? ($_GET['site']) : "comics");
$tag = $_GET['_tagChoice'];

if (!isset($_SESSION['tags'])) {
  $_SESSION['tags'] = array();
}

$tag = $mysqli->real_escape_string($tag);

$_SESSION['tags'][] = $tag;


    foreach ($_SESSION['tags'] as $tag) {

        echo $tag;
    }

$_SESSION['tags'] = array_unique($_SESSION['tags']);

$result = $mysqli->query(
    "SELECT c.*, t.*
    FROM comics c 
    LEFT JOIN comictags ct ON (c.id = ct.comicID) 
    LEFT JOIN tags t ON (t.id = ct.tagID)
    WHERE ct.tagname IN (" . implode(',', $_SESSION['tags']). ")
    OR ct.tagname IS NULL");

 mysqli_close($mysqli);

     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {        
        echo $row['comic_id'];
    }

//session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: you're grouping without aggregate functions, so you're losing all but the first tag found by the db.

Comment: I think you should look at using a persistent cookie, not the session, to store this user tag selection data.  That way when the user comes back days/weeks/months later, on the same browser, their tags will still be available.  Sessions are (and should be) cleaned up after a short period of inactivity.

Comment: @leftclickben okay, I'm not sure how to implement that. Any good resources you know of?

Comment: @Growler Using a cookie is very similar to doing it in `$_SESSION`. Instead of writing to `$_COOKIE`, you must call `setcookie('tags','1,2,3',time() + 86400*600)` (to expire it in 600 days, for example). But the value can be read back from `$_COOKIE['tags']` just as you would read it from `$_SESSION`. Just be sure to sanitize it before passing it into a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join *through* the `comicstags` table to the `tags` table, in order to get the `TagName`.  So add one more `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
 /* Selecting all columns from comics and tags, not from comicstags */
 c.*,
 t.*
FROM 
  comics c
  /* First join matches comics to comicstags */
  INNER JOIN comictags ct ON (c.id = ct.comicID)
  /* Second join pairs comicstags to tags */
  INNER JOIN tags t ON (t.TagID = ct.TagID)
WHERE 
   ct.tagID IN (1, 2, 3)     
   /* Or those which have no tags */
   OR ct.tagID IS NULL
```

The `GROUP BY` was removed since you aren't using aggregates (`COUNT(), SUM(), MIN(), MAX()`, etc).   If you want only unique rows, add `DISTINCT` into the `SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks, Michael! I made an edit above to draw out the logic so I can visualize it- Mind confirming my understanding?

Comment: @Growler Yes, your diagram accurately maps the relationships.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll accept the answer now, but I won't be able to implement it until after work. I may have some more questions

Comment: Quick question, for `ct.tagID IN (1, 2, 3)`, how do I dynamically specify to query only the tags that have been chosen by the user?  It seems I'm hardcoding ct.tagID IN for 1 or 2 or 3.

Comment: Michael, They are in fact in an array. I've updated my code above. Tag selections are being passed to that php script using a $.get AJAX request, and using session to remember the choices. The comics would then been output through a loop given the query results. Would the above code be the correct way of only displaying what the user wanted?

Comment: @Growler No, you would need `"...IN (" . implode(',', $_SESSION['tags']) . ")..."`  and I can't stress this enough , you must have first validated that everything in `$_SESSION['tags']` is an integer.

Comment: $_SESSION['tags'] holds the strings from the user's selection. The reason is when a user clicks a button: `<a href="#" id="business" onclick="getTags(this.id)">Business</a><br />`, jquery function will accept that button id as a string input, and $.get will send that string value to be added to an array. The user's selected tags will be displayed back out for them to see. That being said, I suppose I could do `WHERE ct.tagname IN (" . implode(',', $_SESSION['tags']). ")` instead of "WHERE ct.tagID..."

Comment: @Growler Yes, you can, as long as you've called `$mysqli->real_escape_string()` on them.

Comment: FYI - Final code added above... Anyway, maybe this would be better easier: when a user clicks the tag "business", the <a href id> is set to the same tag number it's referenced by in the database. This way I can load the array up with integers instead of strings?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25114/discussion-between-growler-and-michael-berkowski)

Comment: Michael, This query doesn't work. If I choose tag id 1, the results keep coming back with of the comic ids even though not all comic ids are associated to all tag ids

Comment: @Growler That was the `LEFT JOIN`s as described in the end of the post. I changed them back to inner joins.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
select t.TagId,t.TagNamem,cs.Path from Tag t
inner join ComicTag ct
on(t.TagId =ct.TagId)
inner join Comics cs
on(ct.ComicID = cs.Comic_id)
where t.TagId = $tag_cliked
```

I hope this helps.

Saludos ;)